# onkeypress is not working in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have the following problem with this code:

```
<form>
     <div class="searchBarDiv"> <input class="searchBar" id="search" type="search" 
     placeholder="Suche" onkeypress="search();"> </div>
</form>
```

`search();` won't get fired if i press a key. But when i remove the `<form></form>` everything works fine.

Is there any way to fire `onkeypress` in a form or any other function?

I`m using PhoneGap and jQuery. It won't work in a Browser or on a mobile Device.

Any help would be nice. Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
Solved by A. Wolff: You can't use the id 'search' in a form. Thank you all for you answers and solutions.

Comment: shouldn't it be `onKeyPress`?  Not sure if that matters

Comment: If you using jquery so why you didn't use jq for this one?

Comment: @jiff could you explain what you mean? thanks

Comment: Ok i see, issue is because you are using as id search inside form, it became property of the form. Use e.g: `id="inp_search"`

Comment: For Example: `$('.searchBarDiv').click(function(){ search(); });`

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't want to submit a form. It's just the only way to display the return key as "search" in phonegap for ios

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks!!! The id was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something more like this. Remove the onkeypress from the input, and as per @A.Wolff's comment on the question, change the search input's ID. Then add the following JS on document ready.

```
$("#search_inp").keypress(search);
```

Make sure that the search function takes an event parameter if you need to know which key was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your js function name or input id , your problem is because id and function name are same .

```
<form>
     <div class="searchBarDiv"> <input class="searchBar" id="search" type="search" 
 placeholder="Suche" onkeypress="searchData();"> </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
   function searchData(){
      alert("2222");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was the id. You cant use the id "search" in a form.